# multiple vars not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to take a height given in feet and inches and convert it to inches (eg. 6'1" would be 73"). When I only have one select box (the feet box) I can successfully convert it to inches. But when I add the 'inches' variable and try to add it to the converted 'feet' variable nothing happens.

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function Calculate() {

    var feet = document.getElementById("feet").value;
    var inches = document.getElementbyId("inches").value;

    height = ((feet*12) + inches);

    document.write ('This is your height in inches:<b>   ' + height.toFixed(0) + '</b><br>');
}


</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="form">
Height:
<select id="feet">
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<select id="inches">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="Calculate()" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the type of a text box value?

Comment: You also have a typo in your code, it's getElementById with a capital B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`feet` and `inches` are strings, so `+` concatenates. Multiplying casts `feet` to an integer, so your result for `6'1"` would be 721 (`72+"1"`)

You should convert to integers manually:

```
feet = parseInt(feet,10);
inches = parseInt(inches,10);
```

EDIT: Also, as João pointed out, you mis-capitalised `getElementById` on the second one.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something simple like that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.

First, in this line

```
var inches = document.getElementbyId("inches").value;
```

You forgot to capitalize the `b`. It should be `getElementById`.

Also, `inches` comes from a textbox, which means it's a string, so

```
height = ((feet * 12) + inches);
```

will also be a string because `+` is also a string concatenation operator. Since it's a string, it means that there is no `toFixed` method in its prototype.

You can fix this by passing the string to `Number` or prepending a `+` to make it a number, like this:

```
height = Number((feet * 12) + inches);
//OR
height = +((feet * 12) + inches);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be wrapping the the values of feet and inches in the `parseInt` function to ensure it is an integer.

When using the input `type='submit'` it has different behaviors than regular inputs with `type='button'` so you either need to change the type to `button` or put a `return false` at the end of your calculate function

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a little late, but I threw this into jsFiddle and cleaned up the JS code a little (I swapped it over to jQuery for kicks). It might be worth checking out.

[example - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z5X5/2/)